# Customizing JeasyUI datagrid header

Tags: css, html, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am trying to get a specific design/layout for some info i am displaying, i am using Jeasyui since i like some features that i can get with it and the looks and feels too.

i am trying to get an output as the next image.

[image: http://postimg.org/image/dh9akv9fh/]

I'm having some trouble getting the table to be as i want it to be, for the rotation of the text i found some code on the internet that did help me get it but it makes it very dificult to do more mods to it. i found this css code for it

```
.datagrid-header-row td[rowspan="1"] {
height:100px;
/* need to be properly fixed */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
/* Safari */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
/* Firefox */
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
/* IE */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
/* Opera */
/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

}

The column width is too wide, and i have been playing around with different widths in css and the HTML itself and i cant get it to fit properly. And in some of the header i need word wrap but its not working, had to use `<br/>` but this headers are going dynamically loaded once i get the desired output.

here is a link to my actual coding.

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7d48ntn/4/)

Comment: Try to use height: auto. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga i have to have a fixed height for rotation to work, and height manages the height, not width.